# Create a dictionary from groupby object,Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, group-by

Suppose i have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird'],'Name' : ['Jerry', 'Jerry', 'Flappy Bird', 'Mudkip','Pigeon', 'Mudkip', 'Jerry', 'Pigeon']})
```

and i group it according to the type:

```
print df.groupby(['Type','Name'])['Type'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})

                           Frequency
Type    Name                  
Bird    Flappy Bird          1
        Pigeon               2
Pokemon Jerry                3
        Mudkip               2
```

Could i create a dictionary from the above group ?? The **key** `"Bird"` will have a value of list containing `['Pigeon',Flappy Bird']` note that **higher frequency name** should appear **first** in the **Value list**.

**Expected Output:**

```
dict1 = { 'Bird':['Pigeon','Flappy Bird'] , 'Pokemon':['Jerry','Mudkip'] }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Bird', 'Pokemon', 'Pokemon', 'Bird'],'Name' : ['Jerry', 'Jerry', 'Flappy Bird', 'Mudkip','Pigeon', 'Mudkip', 'Jerry', 'Pigeon']})  
f = df.groupby(['Type','Name'])['Type'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})
f.sort('Frequency',ascending=False, inplace=True)

d = {k:list(f.ix[k].index) for k in f.index.levels[0]}
print(d)
# {'Bird': ['Pigeon', 'Flappy Bird'], 'Pokemon': ['Jerry', 'Mudkip']}
```

The dictionary comprehension will iterate through the outer index ('Bird', 'Pokemon') and then set the value as the inner index for your dictionary.

It is necessary to first sort your `MultiIndex` by the `Frequency` column to get the ordering you wish.

Comment: `DataFrame.sort()` was deprecated and now is removed. Use `f.sort_values()` now.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a one-liner.

```
df.groupby(['Type'])['Name'].apply(lambda grp: list(grp.value_counts().index)).to_dict()

# output
#{'Bird': ['Pigeon', 'Flappy Bird'], 'Pokemon': ['Jerry', 'Mudkip']}
```

The `value_counts` function implicitly groups the `Name` field by count and returns descending order by default.

Bonus: if you want to include counts, you can do the following.

```
df.groupby(['Type']).apply(lambda grp: grp.groupby('Name')['Type'].count().to_dict()).to_dict()

# {'Bird': {'Flappy Bird': 1, 'Pigeon': 2}, 'Pokemon': {'Jerry': 3, 'Mudkip': 2}}
```

Comment: Hi @DanDy : Your Bonus section helped me. Can you please elaborate it, i am wondering how it worked.
Thanks..